# How do we determine if a website uses an API or not?

Tags: python, web-scraping

How do we determine if a website uses an API or not? For ex. If I want to scrap a data from particular website to create a Database, should I check that whether that website allows me to scrap data or does that website allow API? How can I check it?

Comment: You read whatever documentation is available about the service, or you directly contact the service provider and ask them.

Comment: As I have already said in your previous question, using an API and scraping data are unrelated concepts. It is no use to ask the same question again and again without adding context or details. To answer the *should I check ...* question, the answer is *No you should not*, unless you intend to build a scraping bot running on a regular base.

Answer (score 1):

The website owner's wishes should be put in a file called robots.txt. If you use a scraping framework like scrapy, reading and respecting this file is typically built into the framework. If not, you must parse and respect this file manually, which can be some work. Alternatively, read it manually, if you're just scraping a handful of sites.

As an example, check out [https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt](stackoverflow's robots.txt file).